# If url doesn't end with / redirect it to $1/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What i want is real simple. I basically want to do following.

If user opens up

```
http://www.mysite.com/somecategory/somedata
```

Then redirect the user to

```
http://www.mysite.com/somecategory/somedata/
```

i.e adding a

```
/
```

at the end of the url.

I've came to figured it out through the .htaccess, but still it is not working. Here's the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1/
```

should do it.

**Edit:** You should probably also add a second condition so that requests for existing static files are not rewritten (i.e. `index.html` doesn't turn into `index.html/`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1/
```

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work. Said Page not found i.e 404. Some other suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure about anything in it. Now look, what actually I wanted is if in WordPress. If user opens a link like http://server.com/ar/post.. if he opens any post without / at the end.. the htaccess either regex should add / at the end.